# Payouts from ethermine.org rate

Tags: mining, mining-pools

I relatively new to mining in general and I only want to explore what it is like to mine (I'm not really crazy on building rigs or anything but I just want to know the vast ocean of knowledge about mining for ether).

I used my GPU to run some simple hashes and I'm not 100% on the payout. I'm using this mining pool: https://ethermine.org/

On the website, it says that it pays out every 1 ether. So does that mean once I get to 1 ether within that pool, it'll be transferred to me? Or does it mean the entirely of the pool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your balance for the shared work that you contributed to hits 1 ether, you will be payed 1 ether with a 1% fee. You are only paid on the amount of work you contributed to the entire pool. So you'll only receive the single ether in your balance minus of course ethermine's fee.